# Factory girl screws up factories.rb after generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a simple `factories.rb` like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :book_category do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Cateogry #{n}" }
  end

  factory :book do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "Book #{n}" }
  end
end
```

After I run a model generator like `rails g model categorization book:references category:references` my file ends up like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do  factory :categorization do
    book nil
category nil
  end

  factory :post_category do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Cateogry #{n}" }
  end

  factory :book do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "Book #{n}" }
  end
end
```

This happens after every model generation.

Also, if I create a factory before creating a model, and then run a generator to create the model it gives an error saying something like "factory already exists". So I have to wait until I generate the model before adding a factory.

Is this a bug?

*I'm using rails 4.2.4 and factory_girl_rails 4.5.0.*

**Edit:** I tried removing everything from the `factories.rb` file and just adding this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
end
```

After trying to generate a model factory using the command `rails g factory_girl:model book`, this is what I ended up with:

```
FactoryGirl.define do  factory :book do

  end

end
```

Comment: can it have something to do with the line endings in your file? It looks like it adding the correct code, but the indentation and line breaks are set wrong..

Comment: @roman-roman I considered that but I have an ASCII file with LF line-endings on OSX. It should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the whitespace characters present in your factory.rb file. As it comes from the source (https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/blob/master/lib/generators/factory_girl/model/model_generator.rb#L46), it inserts the code after the "\n" character.

Make sure you don't have odd whitespace chars, maybe even regenerate your factories file with `rails g factory_girl:model`.

Comment: I removed everything from the `factories.rb`, and tried the generator command you included, it says `insert spec/factories.rb`, but adds absolutely nothing to that file. I then tried removing that file, and this time it automatically added it to the `spec/factories/my_model.rb`, which is not the behavior I want. This seems like a bug to me.